# Spring Integration Auditing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

First want to say that Spring Integration is some great stuff. Hats off to the team for such a solid framework.

Here is my current challenge. My goal is to handle the crosscutting concern of auditing information within a message flow. For example, store the current SI `Message` in flight, its `Message` ID, all `Payload`s contained within the `Message` and context specific "attributes" that belong to the `Message` such as "orderId", "customerId", "partId", etc.

You can imagine a synchronous flow that may be running for 6 months where reports might need to be run to determine availability of that particular service (e.g. failed transactions versus successful, transactions with particular "attribute" values, transactions in a certain status, failover occurrences, etc).

If I have the following flow:

`gateway->channel1->object-to-json-transformer->channel2->outbound-gateway`

`gateway` has a single method which takes an argument of `MyRequest` and returns a type of `MyResponse`. When the flow starts, I can `wire-tap` `channel1` and route all data on that channel to an audit channel, `auditChannel`, for example.

```
<int:channel id="auditChannel"/>

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter data-source="auditDataSource" channel="auditChannel"  
    query="insert into MESSAGE (PAYLOAD,CREATED_DATE) values (:payload, :createdDate)"
    sql-parameter-source-factory="messageSpelSource"/>

<bean id="messageSpelSource"
      class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="payload"     value="payload.toString()"/>
            <entry key="createdDate" value="new java.util.Date()"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The above subflow (from `channel1` through `auditChannel`) does not result in a `Message` object for the `payload` Map entry. Instead the type is `MyRequest`. This makes sense since I would not want to marshall a `Message` instance outbound, but it still leaves me in a dilemma of not having access to the `Message` envelope for auditing purposes.

If my intention is to provide a generic auditing facility that persists on demand to a common integration database schema (e.g. to a MESSAGE (message_id, correlation_id, payload, timestamp) table and MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE (attribute_id, message_id, name, value) table), how can I ensure that I always have access to the core `Message` instance whenever I `wire-tap` a channel within the flow?

This use case is something that I have had to deal with many years ago with a custom integration framework so I know it is a valid concern.

I hope my request is not too far fetched. Perhaps there is a simple way to handle this and I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Hmm, I realized that I should probably wrap `MyRequest` with a `Message` object and pass a `Message` instance as a parameter to my `gateway` method. That would address being able to `wire-tap` the `Message`. To go further, my guess is that I might need a `filter` or `transformer` before the  to `int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adaptor` to "split" the payload attributes out into a `java.util.Map` that I can then persist as part of the `Message` instance. I have not tried this, but it sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you consider to be the problem; you can add more parameters, such as...

```
<entry key="timestamp" value="headers['timestamp']"/>
```

...what am I missing in your question?

The whole message is available using `"#this"`.

Comment: Ah. Wow. I have to admit that my SpEL knowledge is not too great. So it looks like with SpEL, I can access the message anywhere within my configuration? Also, from examples I found from various sources, I have seen "headers['id']" where I was assuming that was the message id. Instead should I use "#this.id"?

Comment: No; `headers['id']` (or `headers.id`) is correct (or `#this.headers['id']`). `#this` is the message object which has two properties `headers` and `payload`. I generally prefer to to use `headers['foo']` rather than `headers.foo` because the latter won't work if the header is missing (you'll get an exception rather than `null`).

Comment: Initially, I tried to use `headers['id']` as my key to persist the message. Perhaps it failed for me silently due to the incorrect data type when I was expecting a numeric value. Looks like it is a UUID. As far as storing payload attributes like `customerId` as mentioned in the OP, should I be setting those as `header` entries on the message or invent my own structure to persist them as name/value pairs(e.g. message_attribute table)? My intent is to have data that can be queried using SQL if needed by customerId, for example, for a particular date range.

Comment: Yes, it's a UUID; you can use `headers['id'].toString()`. You can also pull arbitrary properties from the payload (assuming they follow the javabean spec and have getters). `payload.customerId` will invoke `payload.getCustomerId()`. You can use dotted expressions and Spel will traverse the object tree. `payload.customer.address.zipCode` will call the getter on each intermediate object.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I believe I have enough to get going now.